# Аналоги YUI

Tags: javascript

Какие есть для веб-интерфейса аналоги не хуже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) (бывший ExtJS)
- [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org)
- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)
- [SproutCore](http://sproutcore.com/)
- [qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/)

...и [много других](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218764/28878).

Answer (score 4):

ext.js , jQuery UI